# Access nested element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[image]I've been trying to access an HTML element with jQuery for several hours now and need some help. Below are the nested structure and I'm trying to get to #mfr_mlsassnidprimaryuserclass.

```
 div id=EntityFormControl
  div id=EntityFormControl_EntityFormView
   div class=tab
    div class=tab-column
      table
       tbody
        tr
         td
          select id=mfr_mlsassnidprimaryuserclass>
```

Inside of this select option, I want to remove some option set like this but it is not working.  Is this even possible?

```
$("#mfr_mlsassnidprimaryuserclass option[value='100000000']").remove();
```

Comment: You're repeating ids on the top two divs.  Ids are expected to be unique by web stanards.  You should fix that.  Edit: And repeating it on the select ....

Comment: Show your options present inside the html select

Comment: The jquery code is working... check https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/865808/

Comment: I see you edited the post, yet the code looks correct. I would review the Console for any errors. Please also provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve This should include jQuery and jQuery UI versions and any other libraries being used.

Comment: No error in the console but the option doesn't get removed.  I'm wondering if jQuery can't find the id because of the id is nested so deep.

Comment: @zAnthony as long as it's the only ID called `mfr_mlsassnidprimaryuserclass`, it will find it regardless of how deep it is nested. Are you sure it is `id` and not `class` attribute? It would be best to provide an actual example.